# Using variables with range function?

Tags: python, variables, range

I'm trying to use the range function with a variable assigned to an input. I have a .csv file and I'm trying to have it so that when the user gives their input as a number from 1-233 that the range will pick that line from the spreadsheet and print out the integer from only the first cell. However I can only get it to cycle down to the last line of the spreadsheet, regardless of what the input is. Below is the code.

```
var=input('Please give a number >0 and <= the number of students -->')

for line in file:
    line=range(var)
print(line)
```

How can I get it to only output the line that the user inputs?

Comment: What do you think `line=range(var)` is *doing*? In any case, you are iterating through the entire file: `for line in file:`... perhaps you meant to do something else with that...

Comment: This is not even close to correct code (given the question). Secondly, picking out a specific item from a `csv` file might be better done with the `pandas` module

Comment: @D.L no, that can trivially be handled with the python built ins.

Answer (score 1):

This would do what you want but it's a bit fugly

```py
with open('input.csv') as csvfile:
    content = csvfile.readlines()

this_needs_to_be_an_int = int(input(f'Please give a number >0 and <= {len(content)}\n'))

print(content[this_needs_to_be_an_int])
```

What it does is it reads the contents of the csv file into a list (using `readlines()`) and then gets the element of the list based on the input.

CSV files usually contain a header line, but if it doesn't you'll need to offset `this_needs_to_be_an_int` as lists are [zero index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-based_numbering) based.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit prettier than the `openfile` method, but it does require [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org).

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('input.csv')

row_number = int(input('enter row number to print: '))
print(df.loc[[row_number]])
```

This imports the whole csv into a dataframe and extracts the row that the user wants. It is useful if already using this module, but otherwise, you can also do the same with the standard library modules   `csv` or the `readlines` command for an open file.

Comment: What's `readfile`? I couldn't find it in the stdlib.

Comment: @wjandrea i meant readlines command (not a module) or `csv` module.  will ammend that bit.

Answer (score 0):

Use `itertools.islice` to skip the first `n-1` lines; then `next` can be used to get the `n`th line.

```
from itertools import islice

var = int(input('Please give a number >0 and <= the number of students -->'))
print(next(islice(file, var-1)))
```